# Ad-hoc deployment of Windows Phone 7 app to testers

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment, ad-hoc-distribution

I am developing an application that targets multiple devices, iOS, Android and WP7. For iOS I can use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) to deploy new versions of the app to testers. Likewise on Android it is possible to use [Zubhium](https://www.zubhium.com/) to do practically the same as TestFlight just for Android.

So my questions is:
Is there a similar way to easily distribute an application to testers, assuming they all have their devices registered on AppHub as developer devices, on the WP7 platform? I do not really need all the statistics or the error reporting TestFlight and Zubhium provides, but it would of course be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the new format you can upload your application on dev center (the new App Hub) as beta app and enter the mail ids of your testers. Once you complete your testing, you may need to re-release the app again for MS certification. Please see the screenshot and visit the `https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/AppSubmission/Application` for further details.
[image]

Comment: You can certainly do this, but be aware that you can't update the app when you do so. You deploy the beta and then wait 90 days gathering comments on it. I actually opened a ticket on this and was told it's by design. You can open more betas and copy the user emails between them, but that won't magically update the phones of the existing testers and they'll have to install and uninstall. IT might be simpler just to email xaps around.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Glad to learn from your experience. In that case I agree to pass the `.xap` around.

Comment: However, if I pass an XAP, the tester will need to have access to a computer with Windows Phone SDK to use the Application Deployment tool?

Comment: Correct! The tester will need the deployment tool that comes with the SDK. It is described here `http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Deploying-WP7-XAP-files-to-a-device-or-emulator` or you may also refer this `http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1016766`

Comment: Your first link seems to be broken when copy/pasting it. This seems to work though: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Deploying-WP7-XAP-files-to-a-device-or-emulator

Comment: Thanks for posting it. I don't know why it appears to be broken.